# Upsert a subdocument in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to add successively subdocuments to a document.The goal is that each subdocument only appears once in the array. And if it exists it should be updated. I think this is called "upsert".

#### Example Schema

```js
var playlistSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    tracks:[
        {
            name: String,
            artist: String
        }]
});
```

#### Query

```js
var query = {'name': 'Playlist1'},
    update1 = {'$push': { 'tracks': {'name' : 'First Track', 'artist': 'artist'}}},
    update2 = {'$push': { 'tracks': {'name' : 'First Track', 'artist': 'new artist'}}},
    update3 = {'$push': { 'tracks': {'name' : 'Second Track', 'artist': 'artist'}}},
    options = {upsert: true};

playlistSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update1, options, function (err, playlist) {});
playlistSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update2, options, function (err, playlist) {});
playlistSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update3, options, function (err, playlist) {});
```

#### What I get

```js
"name": "Playlist1", 
"tracks": [{"name": "First Track", "artist": "artist"},
           {"name": "First Track", "artist": "new artist"},
           {"name": "Second Track", "artist": "artist"}]
```

#### What I aim for

```js
"name": "Playlist1" ,   
"tracks": [{"name": "First Track", "artist": "new artist"},
           {"name": "Second Track", "artist": "artist"}]
```

Probably I have to Query a specific subdocument but I don't know how.

Comment: Upsert will do an update if it matches the query parameters, and if it doesn't match anything, will perform an insert.  See here (ctrl-f for upsert):  

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After replacing **$push** with **$addToSet** it is working as expected.

```
var query = {'name': 'Playlist1'},
    update1 = {'$addToSet': { 'tracks': {'name' : 'First Track', 'artist': 'artist'}}},
    options = {};

playlistSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update1, options, function (err, playlist) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the track is already added, you can use a positional update to update the element in the array.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/)

For instance:

```
db.playlists.update(
    {'name': 'Playlist1', 'tracks.name': 'First Track'}, 
    {'$set': { 'tracks.$.artist': 'new artist'}}
);
```

This will find 'Playlist1' and be able to determine where in the tracks array it matches on 'First Track' and store that in the '$' operator.  Then when you update the artist in the $set, it will override the variable with the new one.

This might not be the exact solution to what you're looking for, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.